# Automatically move object forward,left,right at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game project in which I want to automatically move an object forward as well as left or right at the same time as like the temple run character, I'm using the following simple script to move the object forward:

```
void Start () {

    }

void Update () {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward *Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

}
```

I don't know how to do the rest.

Comment: You might want to consider also asking this over at [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track so far, but I assume you want the movement to the left and right to occur based on user input?

**This is an example of code that would account for the input of left and right, but it may need to be customized for your use case.**

```
public float movementSpeed = 6f;

void Update ()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    //Strafe your object Left and right based on user input                       
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed);      
}
```

**Example of a method that you could use to rotate the player:**

In order to have your player turn 90 degrees, you will need to rotate the actual object. Based on your actual logic/gameplay, you could do something as simple as:

```
void Update() {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    //Strafe your object Left and right based on user input                       
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed);    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("q")) { 
        this.transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) { 
        this.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
    }
}
```

**For Accelerometer Input:**

```
void Update() {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.acceleration.x > 0) {
        this.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
    }
    else if (Input.acceleration.x < -0) {
        this.transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I exactly want to do,I want my object to move like the temple run character.means it will move forward and left/right at the same time using my phone motion.

Comment: Ah, sorry i just remembered how temple run pivots rather than just moving right or left.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @alterego I can give you some suggestions. Check out the edits i made.

Comment: Thank you but is there any way I can do the left right movement based on my phone's tilting?

Comment: @alterego you would probably need to use `Input.Acceleration`. See my update

Comment: how i can change  z axis of object by Acceleration